# Adding a Node to a SQL Server 2008 Cluster Returns "The current SKU is invalid." Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, cluster-computing

When I try to add a second node to my SQL Server 2008 cluster the installer throws an error, **"The current SKU is invalid."** What's up I know the key is correct, I used it on the first node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh! It's a bug.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=363036

That's jacked up that I'm forced to use the command line for any additional nodes. I'm not apposed but seriously, did Microsoft even attempt to test the installer?

Answer (score 0):

Update all nodes to SP1 and try again!!!